# Sort JavaScript object by string property value

Tags: javascript, sorting, javascript-objects

Ok, so I'm getting some data from a server like this: `myVar = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText)`. Now, my var looks something like:

```
{
    someData1234:{
        score: "5",
        loc: "NY"
    },

    someData4321:{
        score: "70",
        loc: "MH"
    },

    someData4123:{
        score: "43",
        loc: "NG"
    }
}
```

How can i sort through the object so it orders it by the score in an descending order? i tried other solutions but didn't seem to work correctly as i need the same object(or an array of objects) back but just re-ordered

Comment: object cant be sortable.Array only have index to sorting

Comment: There is no concept of "sort" in objects, because there is [no order guarantee in JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already noted, [JavaScript object property order is not guaranteed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order), so you will have to convert your data into an array of objects and then sort. Following example uses `Object.entries` and `map` to convert the initial object into an array, then sorts by parsing a numerical value from `score` in each object:

```js
const obj = { someData1234: { score: "5", loc: "NY" }, someData4321: { score: "70", loc: "MH" }, someData4123: { score: "43", loc: "NG" } };
const arr = Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => ({[k]: v}));
const sorted = arr.sort((a, b) => {
  return parseInt(a[Object.keys(a)[0]].score) - parseInt(b[Object.keys(b)[0]].score);
});

console.log(sorted);
// [{"someData1234":{"score":"5","loc":"NY"}},{"someData4123":{"score":"43","loc":"NG"}},{"someData4321":{"score":"70","loc":"MH"}}]
```

Comment: seems like your code would work! cant test it right now but i will try it when i get home! thanks!

Comment: your code does seem to work correctly! thanks but would it be too much to ask how can i make it sort in a descending order? i made a typo in the post... if its too much work don't bother. i will try to fix it! :) thanks again!

Comment: @kriskotooBG - you can reverse the sort order by replacing the `return` line with `return parseInt(b[Object.keys(b)[0]].score) - parseInt(a[Object.keys(a)[0]].score);` - `a - b` sorts ascending, `b - a` sorts descending.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var array = [{  
    "EmployeeName": "John",  
    "Experience": "12",  
    "Technology": "SharePoint"  
}, {  
    "EmployeeName": "Charles",  
    "Experience": "9",  
    "Technology": "ASP.NET"  
}, {  
    "EmployeeName": "Jo",  
    "Experience": "3",  
    "Technology": "JAVA"  
}, {  
    "EmployeeName": "Daine",  
    "Experience": "7",  
    "Technology": "Sql Server"  
}, {  
    "EmployeeName": "Zain",  
    "Experience": "6",  
    "Technology": "C#"  
}];  
//Comparer Function  
function GetSortOrder(prop) {  
    return function(a, b) {  
        if (a[prop] > b[prop]) {  
            return 1;  
        } else if (a[prop] < b[prop]) {  
            return -1;  
        }  
        return 0;  
    }  
}  

array.sort(GetSortOrder("EmployeeName")); //Pass the attribute to be sorted on  
document.write("Sorted Employee Names : ");  
for (var item in array) {  
    document.write("<br>" + array[item].EmployeeName);  
}  

array.sort(GetSortOrder("Technology")); //Pass the attribute to be sorted on  
document.write("<br><br> Sorted Technology Names : ");  
for (var item in array) {  
    document.write("<br>" + array[item].Technology);  
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you for the answer! but I'm getting kind of confused :( my question was about sorting a number not names ... Thanks Anyways!

Comment: Please provide some explanation with your code in [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
  let something = {
    someData1234: {
      score: "5",
      loc: "NY"
    },

    someData4321: {
      score: "70",
      loc: "MH"
    },

    someData4123: {
      score: "43",
      loc: "NG"
    }
  };
  let someArray = [];
  let myArray = []
  Object.keys(something).map((som, ind) => {
    myArray.push(`${Object.values(Object.entries(something)[ind][1])[0]}` + ind);
  });
  myArray.sort((a, b) => {
    return a - b
  });
  console.log(myArray);

  for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
      let obj=Object.entries(something)[myArray[i].charAt(myArray[i].length-1)];
      console.log(obj);
      let key= obj[0];
      let value=obj[1];
    someArray.push({[key]:value})
  }
  let myOrderedObject;
  let obj;
  for(let i=0;i<someArray.length;i++){
     obj=someArray[i];
    console.log(obj);
     myOrderedObject={...myOrderedObject,...obj};
     console.log(myOrderedObject);
    console.log(i);
  }
  console.log('mY ordered Object ',myOrderedObject);

  console.log(someArray);
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

You could move the keys (like "someData1234") inside the objects (as the value of a "key" property), and put those objects in an array sorted by your liking: that way you have all information at hand:

```js
const data = {someData1234:{score: "5",loc: "NY"},someData4321:{score: "70",loc: "MH"},someData4123:{score: "43",loc: "NG"}};

const result = Object.entries(data).map(([key, val]) => ({key, ...val}))
                     .sort((a,b) => a.score - b.score);
                     
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -3):

```js
const data = {
    someData1234:{
        score: "5",
        loc: "NY"
    },

    someData4321:{
        score: "70",
        loc: "MH"
    },

    someData4123:{
        score: "43",
        loc: "NG"
    }
};

// Use an Intl.Collator to construct a function that will sort number strings
const naturalSort = new Intl.Collator(undefined, { numeric: true }).compare;

const sortProperties = obj => Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj) // Get the list of properties
  .sort((a, b) => naturalSort(obj[a].score, obj[b].score)) // Order based on the score
  .reduce( // Reduce the ordered properties to create a new object
    (result, prop) => {
      result[prop] = obj[prop];
      return result;
    }, {}
  );

console.log(sortProperties(data));
```